# Couldn't Find A Package.json File In "/var"

Tags: javascript, json, linux, yarnpkg

I'm bottle-necked here.  When I `yarn run dev` I get

> yarn run v1.22.4 error *Couldn't find a package.json file in "/var"*

I think this is because it's looking for a [script](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run)

What script? Does it want me to make a script or should there be one from the program I am trying to install which is [Cerebro](https://github.com/KELiON/cerebro) thanks.

I asked for help in [Gitter Cerebro Channel](https://gitter.im/KELiON-cerebro/Lobby?source=orgpage) before posting here.

Comment: you need to cd into your project folder fist, before running it

Comment: Thanks.  in /urs/lib/cerebro I run "yarn run dev" and get 
yarn run v1.22.4
$ concurrently --kill-others "yarn run hot-server" "yarn run start-hot"
/bin/sh: concurrently: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Comment: did you do yarn install first

Comment: yup, "yum install yarn"

"yarn -v"
1.22.4

Comment: i mean "yarn install" inside your project folder

Comment: Likely not.  So, inside /usr/lib/cerebro I ran "yum install yarn" and got Package yarn-1.22.4-1.noarch already installed and latest version

Comment: i mean "yarn install"

Comment: "yarn install" doesn't work. I am on CentOS7 the command is "yum install yarn"

Comment: no, you don't understall, "yarn install" is different from "yum install yarn" it's not the same command, please try it before replying again

Comment: Apologies.  Wow! The output was too long so I sent to termbin.com sorry if this is not proper https://termbin.com/7nsa

Comment: In /usr/lib/cerebro/node_modules I ran "yarn install | nc termbin.com 9999" https://termbin.com/ruab


yarn run dev | nc termbin.com 9999 | https://termbin.com/tj8zg

Comment: ok, you succeed, the new error is because /use/lib is a root owned folder, so there is an permission error. you can force the issue by running "sudo yarn run dev", but i recommend you move your project folder to your home folder(/home/youusername/), with will resolve the permissions

Comment: In /usr/lib/cerebro/node_modules I ran "yarn run dev" it looked like it was working however the cursor went idle for a few hours.  Never seen that happen before so I stopped the process https://pastebin.com/iTr95h3d | I'm not exactly sure where the project folder is.  In /usr/lib there are two potential locations "cerebro-tools" and "cerebro-ui".  Do I move both of those directories? What is the benefit of moving the directories to ~/ ?